# Find post by date

Tags: support, questions, search, dates

I have a funny problem. I can not find a certain post on http://stackoverflow.com, but I remember the approximate date of creating this post.

Is it possible to find the post, knowing only the date is was created?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries

Comment: @Seth that would work, but it's supported by the Search functionality as well.

Comment: @Glorfindel Ahh, thanks :) Learnt something.

Comment: You'll need more than date. StackOverflow gets [about 8,000 questions posted each day](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks for edit grammar mistakes, but greeting and my design look better, in my opinion.do not be offended.

Comment: The consensus is that greetings such as "Good Day" should be [removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) from posts.

Comment: @Glorfindel ok, I will remove it, thanks for the clarifications

Comment: You're welcome, no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with [advanced searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching). For example, to find all posts on *this* site created on the first two days of this year, you'll need the following query:

```
created:2016-01-01..2016-01-02
```

The results are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2016-01-01..2016-01-02).

On Stack Overflow, this will give a rather long list of results, so you'll need to combine it with other search terms (keywords, tags, etc.)